# How do I read multiple serialized objects of the same type out of a QDataStream?

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently trying to implement a serialization system in my code, which stores multiple objects of a type in a file. This works pretty well, I usually just append them one by one with the OpenMode `QIODevice::Append`. No problems here.

However, on the other side, when reading these objects, I run into trouble.

This is what it looks like right now:

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
MyObject entry;
out >> entry;
entries.push_back(entry);
```

It works as expected, but it only reads in one element. However, I want to read all objects inside the file, not just the first one occuring.

How could this be done? I am pretty unsure whether there is a possibility for my stream to know the size my object is taking in the file while being in serialized form, but there has to be some way?

Comment: What's the problem ? Can't you just iterate ?

Comment: @Ilya I hope so, but I can't quite find out how to iterate it. I can't get it to work with foreach or the iterator loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate on the entire stream:

```
while( out.atEnd() == false ) {
  MyObject entry;
  out >> entry;
  entries.push_back(entry);  
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I thought the stream would just read the whole file at once, and treat it as one whole string/object.